# Parse keyword="value"

Tags: parsing, hive, apache-pig

I'm looking for a HIVE UDF that will parse an array of data into a tabular form.
If there's nothing in HIVE, a PIG example would be appreciated.

The input is in this format:

> date timestamp key1="val1" key2="val2" key3="val3" year month day
>
> date timestamp key1="val4" key2="val5" key3="val6" year month day

Would like the results to be a table where the column names are the keywords and the results are the values. Such as:

results:

> column_name   key1    key2    key3
>
> results       val1    val2    val3
>
> ```
>           val4    val5    val6
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding about your issue,i am pointing one solution.

first create a table in hive.

```
 create table example1(dates string,timestamps string,key1 map<string,string>,key2 map<string,string>,key3 map<string,string>,year int, month string,day string) row format delimited fields terminated by ' ' map keys terminated by '=';
```

create another table like

```
create table example2(key1 string,key2 string,key3 string)
```

insert the data into second table from first table

```
insert into  table example2  select key1["key1"],key2["key2"],key3["key3"]  from example1;
```

output:

select * from example2;

```
"val1"  "val2"  "val3"
"val4"  "val5"  "val6"
```

in this, i am not concentrating on data types.